# TypeError: identifier.replace is not a function - Sequelize

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I have two tables `StudyGroup` and `Students` and between them is a many-to-many relationship, solved by the intersection table `StudentGroups`. I am trying to find out how many Students each `StudyGroup` has. Below is my code

```
    router.route("/studocu/students/count").get((req, res) => {
    GrupDeStudiu.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'Nume'],
        include: {
            model: Student
        }
    }).then(response => res.json(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
})
```

Everytime I run it, I keep getting the same error `TypeError: identifier.replace is not a function`

update 2

```
router.route("/studocu/students/count").get((req, res) => {
    GrupDeStudiu.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'Nume'],
        include: {
            model: Student
             through: {
                attributes: [[seq.fn('COUNT', seq.col('id')), 'Numar Studenti']]
             }
        },
        group: ['Grup_De_Studiu.id', 'Grup_De_Studiu.Nume']
    }).then(response => res.json(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should correct `attributes` definition like this:

```
attributes: [[seq.fn('count', seq.col('id')), 'Numar Studenti']]
```

Because `[seq.fn('count', seq.col('id')), 'Numar Studenti']` is a definition of a single attribute and attributes are an array strings and/or such attribute arrays or an object with `include` or `exclude` keys.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I applied the changes you suggested but the error is still there

Comment: Does `Student` have a valid value?

Comment: Yes, it does have a valid value, each table has values inserted into them

Comment: I mean the variable `Student` in above  piece of code

Comment: So I'm not sure what you mean, Student variable holds the code that creates the Student table using sequelize.

Comment: So you absolutely sure `Student` has a value at that line? Try to remove `through` option to check if a query works w/o it

Comment: I removed through option and it doesn't work, the new error is : `DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Ambiguous column name 'Nume'`. If I remove everything starting with include, the query works

Comment: So I renamed a column in the Student table (Nume) and tried the query again ( without the through and group options ), and it worked. But when I try it with the through option I get the same error as in the begining.

Comment: Can you update your post with the last version of your query?

Comment: I added the code, in this format the error is the same (identifier.replace is not a function)

Comment: I suppose it stucks on an aggregate attribute. You already have an amount of students in each GrupDeStudiu by including Student model. just look at `length` of students array